# What PHP Array Function do I use to convert a multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to convert this.

```
$data1 = array(
    array('value' => '100.00', 'total' => '32'),
    array('value' => '10.00', 'total' => '13'),
    array('value' => '200.00', 'total' => '39'),
    array('value' => '190.00', 'total' => '11'),
);
```

into this

```
$data2 = array(
    'value' => array(0 => '100.00', 1 => '10.00', 2 => '200.00', 3 => '190.00'),
    'total' => array(0 => '32', 1 => '13', 2 => '39', 3 => '11')
);
```

I can obviously do this in a roundabout way by iterating over the top array, while appending to a series of arrays, but I figured that there must be a php array function that I don't know about that can do this more concisely.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Values are floats and integers (if it makes any difference), I've just added them as strings in the example code because it's easier to read IMO. Final array order should match the initial order. I'll award the correct answer to the least LOC providing performance isn't significantly worse that the 'long' version. PHP 5.4.

Comment: You are looking into [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) kind of operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php // php 5.4 array syntax

$new = array_reduce($data1, function (&$result, $item)
    {
        $result['value'][] = $item['value'];
        $result['total'][] = $item['total']; 
        return $result;
    },
    ['value' => [], 'total' => []]);
```

'value' and 'total' are arbitrary names, so you're not going to get a one-liner php library function to do this.

You can refactor this code into a function if you want to...

```
function array_rotate($data) {
    $k = array_keys($data[0]);
    return array_reduce($data, function (&$r, $i) use ($k) {
        $r[$k[0]][] = $i[$k[0]];
        $r[$k[1]][] = $i[$k[1]]; 
        return $r;
    }, [$k[0] => [], $k[1] => []]);
}
```

I generalised @matthew's code, this allows an arbitrary number of keys (instead of 2):

```
function array_rotate2($data) {
    return array_combine(array_keys($data[0]), 
        array_map(function ($field) use ($data) {
              return array_map(function($row) use ($field) { return $row[$field]; }, $data);
            }, array_keys($data[0])));
}
```

Comment: Aren't you passing `$result` by reference?

Comment: @Mike yep, that's the recommended method signature in the docs

Comment: Weird, so does it work with PHP 5.4? From the docs: "_As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error._"

Comment: `$foo = foo(&$a)` is invalid. `function foo(&$a) { $a = 42; }` continues to be valid.

Comment: Added a generalisation of @Matthew 's method :)

Answer (score 5):

If PHP had an `array_pluck` function, it would be simple.

```
function array_pluck(array $array, $field)
{
  return array_map(function($row) use ($field) { return $row[$field]; }, $array);
}

$data2 = array(
  'value' => array_pluck($data1, 'value'),
  'total' => array_pluck($data1, 'total')
);
```

I think that's about as easy as it is to read, but you'll be looping over the entire array once per field, so it's hardly the optimal solution.

Personally, this is a situation where I'd probably stick with the `foreach` solution but try to wrap it inside some reusable function.

Comment: Well now it has an `array_pluck` function :))

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a function using a simple foreach():

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array('value' => '100.00', 'total' => '32'),
    array('value' => '10.00', 'total' => '13'),
    array('value' => '200.00', 'total' => '39'),
    array('value' => '190.00', 'total' => '11'),
);

$newArray = array();
$i=0;
foreach($data as $value){
    $newArray["value"][] = $data[$i]["value"]; 
    $newArray["total"][] = $data[$i]["total"]; 
    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Prints this:

```
Array
(
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100.00
            [1] => 10.00
            [2] => 200.00
            [3] => 190.00
        )

    [total] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 39
            [3] => 11
        )
)
```

Comment: I knew that. Thanks for typing it out but I'm looking for something that does this more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

```
$final = array();
foreach($data1 as $array) {
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $final[$key] = isset($final[$key]) ? $final : array();
    $final[$key][] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others are saying I don't think there is a one-liner.  Here is a reusable foreach function that should work

```
function array_multi_key_combine($a, $keys = array()) {
    $b = array();
    foreach($a as $v) {
        foreach($keys as $k) {
            if(isset($v[$k])) $b[$k][] = $v[$k];
        }
    }
    return $b;
}
$data2 = array_multi_key_combine($data1, array('value', 'total'));
```